# Laravel use default email confirmation for guests

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about my code for confirmation email guests. I have a comment system. When guest read a post, he can write a comment. When he add a comment, guest need confirm email (on comment form, I have field for email). How I can correctly do email confirmation? How In Laravel, when user register.

Now I have table "guests" and a model Guest, with columns: `name`, `email`, `email_token` and `email_verified_at` (how in users table).

In model guest I have function:

```
public function sendEmailNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify((new ReviewEmailNotification($token)));
}
```

When comment is created, I call observed function `created` and send email:

```
public function created(Review $review)
{
    Auth::guest() ? $review->sendEmailNotification($review->email_token) : '';
}
```

My notification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class ReviewEmailNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
public $token;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Verify comment'))
        ->line(Lang::getFromJson('Please confirm your Email:'))
        ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Confirm E-Mail'), url(config('app.url') . route('revemail', $this->token)))
        ->line(Lang::getFromJson('...'));
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
}
```

My function for confirm email:

```
public function activateEmail($token = null)
{
    $guest = Guest::where('email_token', $token)->first();

    if ($review) {
        $guest->email_verified_at = now();
        $guest->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

And when email is verified I create record on guests table.

This solution is working. But how I can go away from `email_token`? In users table I have only `email_verified_at` without column token. And I want do token with expire date, how in laravel. Can I use default laravel email confirmation for guests?

Answer (score 0):

Simple modify your sendEmailNotification currently which is accepting $token change it to email and in your function where you are using token change it to email like this:

open this function **ReviewEmailNotification**

`modify like this Review::where('email',$email)`

want more help then post the complete code of **ReviewEmailNotification**

Comment: code is not complete posted , you are also using route : route('revemail', $this->token)) in which  you querying with token

Comment: finally i understand your query, you have to change the code.... Dont use the user table for that because in every post/article will publish new comment/review so guest table will be good and add post_id, user_id for email confirmation , so your new function look like this public function activateEmail($token = null)
{
    $guest = Guest::where('post_id', $post_id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

    if ($review) {
        $guest->email_verified_at = now();
        $guest->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('home');
}

Answer (score 0):

finally i understand your query, you have to change the code.... Dont use the user table for that because in every post/article will publish new comment/review so guest table will be good and add post_id, user_id for email confirmation , so your new function look like this

```
public function created(Review $review)
{
    Auth::guest() ? $review->sendEmailNotification($review-> post_id,$review->user_id,) : '';
}



public function activateEmail($token = null)
{
    $guest = Guest::where('post_id', $post_id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

    if ($review) {
        $guest->email_verified_at = now();
        $guest->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('home');
}



public function sendEmailNotification($user_id,$post_id)
{
    $this->notify((new ReviewEmailNotification($post_id,$user_id )));
}
```